# Java Identifier Not Working

Tags: java

So I have a car class and a car tester class. Here is the car class:

```
package main;

public class Car {

    private long distance;
    private double newDistance;
    private double gasAmount;
    private double newGasAmount;

    // Contrsuctor 
    Car(){
        distance = 0;
    }


    Car(long newDistance){
        distance = newDistance;
    }
    //Accessor
    public long getDistance(){
        return distance;
    }

    public double getGasInTank(){
        return gasAmount;
    }

    //Mutator
    public void drive(double distance){
        newDistance = distance;
    }    
    public void addGas(double gasAmount){
        newGasAmount = gasAmount;
    }
}
```

And here is the problem. In my carTester class, why doesnt `myVehicle.drive();` work??
It underlines it in red (netBeans) and says "package myVehicle doesn't exist"

```
package main;

public class CarTester {

    Car myVehicle = new Car();
    myVehicle.drive();
    double gasLeft = myVehicle.getGasInTank();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will issue this message when you attempt to invoke an operation on an `Object` in the class block.

You need to use a `main` method in `CarTester`. Also you need to supply a `double` `distance` value as per your `drive` method.

```
public class CarTester {
  public final static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myVehicle = new Car();
    myVehicle.drive(33.2);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Presiate it. Solved the problem! I created a new class and deleted the main one so I overlooked that

Comment: Thanks! Just got around to it, I'm new to stack overflow, but I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

run your code in CarTester class inside of the method. for example public final static void main(String[] args) {...}...

e.g.

```
package main;

public class CarTester {
  public final static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myVehicle = new Car();
    myVehicle.drive();
    double gasLeft = myVehicle.getGasInTank();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what the problem is is that **you don't have a method** in class `CarTester`. The compiler is complaining that it cannot find a package with the name of `myVehicle`, because it is trying to interpret the line `myVehicle.drive();` as a **type**. You need to change the class `CarTester` to something like:

```
public class CarTester
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.drive(10.0);
        double gasLeft = car.getGasInTank();
    }
}
```